# Does connecting to a VPN router reveal your public IP address?

Tags: router, vpn, ip

This could easily be found out with experimentation but.. I hadn't had the chance to..

Is it a thing you can set in the router's settings..?

Comment: Reveal it to whom exactly?

Comment: @grawity what do you mean? The only way it could be revealed is it was seen in the router logs. the router is the only thing that can log it.. (hmm.. i see now, i shouldn't have used the word "reveal")

Comment: maybe I meant.. logged.
"Do VPN routers *log* your public IP address if you log into one?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it reveals your actual IP yo the VPN server and this can't be tweaked it changed in VON settings.

The VPN endpoint you connect to needs to be able to send packets to your actual IP so it can tunnel them. The semi-exception would be are if your provider is using Carrier Grade NAT and sharing your IP with multiple others, in which case the address is shown.

You could obfusicate this by routing a VPN I've a VPN (or more then 1), in which case the first VPN would know your IP, the second the IP if the first VPN and so on. Of-course, multylsyer VPNs cause their own issues - speed, mtu are chief among these.

Comment: Thanks, of course it shows the IP, how will it know who to give the data to *face palm*